# How to flip the sign of a variable depending on a condition, in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

The following doesn't work (there must also be a more succinct way of doing it):

```
ask turtles
      [
        ifelse return > 0
        [
          set tot-demand-contrarians (-(tot-demand-contrarians))
          set tot-demand-followers ((tot-demand-followers))
        ]
        [
          set tot-demand-contrarians ((tot-demand-contrarians))
          set tot-demand-followers (-(tot-demand-followers))
        ]
      ]
```

Comment: what doesn't work? are you getting an error message and, if so, what? or what behaviour are you getting that is wrong?

Comment: the signs are not changing

Answer (score 0):

Half of your clauses set a variable to itself anyway so they're not needed. I suspect NetLogo is reading the '-' as an instruction to subtract, but you haven't said what to subtract it from. You could do something like:

```
set x (0 - x)    ; the brackets are optional, for clarity
```

But personally I feel that it is more readable to multiply by -1

```
ask turtles
[ ifelse return > 0
  [ set tot-demand-contrarians (-1 * tot-demand-contrarians) ]
  [ set tot-demand-followers (-1 * tot-demand-followers) ]
]
```